# Reading your own application file in android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to read my own android application file from code.
I mean to say suppose my filename is abc.apk which has got installed on the phone.Now through the same application (abc.apk) , I want to read abc.apk file byte by byte .
Is it possible through code.

EDIT : I am editing the question for further usage.
How can I get the current filename of my android application through native code.

Thanks ,
Chetan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Here is example project that does it: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1923577/android_native_read_apk.7z

It includes all the source code (java nad C++).
If you install apk file from bin folder and run on device it will print out to android log "D/TEST (18107): First 4 bytes = 50 4b 03 04". And that is exactly first 4 bytes of apk file (check it with hexeditor).
I am running this on non-rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this possible on a stock device. data/app/ directory cannot be accessed directly without root.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can read any file in your /data/app directory. Of course - not in other directories.

Comment: On a stock(non-rooted) Epic Touch 4g (Galaxy sII) if I download "Root Browser" from the market it will let me go into some of the system folders. But when I go into data it shows no files/folders. I have never tried this programmatically but it seems like they'd show up in the browser if the app was able to get programmatic access to that folder. Could be possible though, I have never tested it and I am only going off of what I think I know =)

Comment: I doubt this is possible on non-rooted devices. Android intentionally blocks access to those folders to prevent users from mucking about with APK files. I'd hope to be proven wrong for the asker's sake but I'm pretty sure this isn't possible since it's meant to be a "security" thing

Comment: No, it is possible. Here is example project that does it: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1923577/android_native_read_apk.7z If you run it it will print out to android log "D/TEST    (18107): First 4 bytes = 50 4b 03 04". And that is exactly first 4 bytes of apk file (check it with hexeditor). I am running this on non-rooted device.

Comment: Fair enough, good find @Martins Mozeiko Can you change your link to go to the apk file? 7zip extracts it as a folder instead of an apk file. Also you should put that into an answer post instead of comment =)

Comment: It is not apk file. It is archive of android project that includes Java and C++ source code. You can find and install apk file from bin directory in there.

Comment: You should open new question for new question.. You want to get name of apk file? There isn't really reliable way how to do it from NDK. You could try following though: invoking "ps"  command and parsing output to find NAME of your process id (PID). Then you can read "/data/system/packages.list" to find apk file (last column) for application name (first column). But this will require to have busybox (for ps), and pakcages.list is not present on all devices.

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko : yes But If I install busybox on my phone , Do I need to root my phone. Can't I follow the procedure of windows c to locate the file ?

Comment: Yes, you need root for busybox. What is "procedure of windows c" ?